# Is there any Office Web Apps Server Api available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-wopi, office-web-components

I want to allow user to be able to edit office documents online within the web application.
I have come to know that I can do it easily by installing [Web App Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455(v=office.15)?tduid=(a828d8925394e2e49fc2d91add18709e)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-799.Caxuvz33LFKryeF6BQ)().)

But it requires a separate isolated server for installing it. Or I need to install it on virtual machine.

I was wondering if is there any api available (which already have Web App Server installed on it), which I can use directly with my web application to fulfill my requirement?.

Answer (score 3):

The web-based Office document editing is achieved by implementing MS-WOPI protocol. The protocol consists of three parties - a WOPI Server (app serving the files...typically your app or SharePoint), a WOPI Client (Office Web Apps) and a client browser.

[image: MS WOPI]

Unless you want to implement your own WOPI client (which should be possible but I haven't seen anyone trying to go that path) you have to use Office Web Apps or its younger brother Office Online Server.

Comment: Hi rocky,
Thanks for your reply, but I have one more question, how do I use Office Web Apps? Do I need to install Office Web Apps on different isolated server?.

Comment: I wouldn't say you "need to", I'd rather say it's recommended. One important prerequisite is that the OWA machine is connected to an AD domain. This can be overcame e.g. by installing Domain Controller role.